# Architecture decision: return std::future or provide a callback?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, future

I am designing an API interface for Arinc429 devices. Various suppliers provide different features within devices, so I decided to have a set of common and expected methods that must be implemented for every entity.
In particular, I have a question regarding the output channel. It provides a method for a single output of a byte array, and the output itself is asynchronous after the method is called. One of the devices implements interrupts which can be caught via OS utilities (`WaitForSingleObject` in Windows).

So in this particular case I have an object which implements `IArinc429Device`, it:

- implements method `CaptureInterrupt` that invokes a particular channel's callback when interrupt occurs;
- holds a thread that runs `CaptureInterrupt`;

```
void ArincPCI429_3::CaptureInterrupt()
{
    HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, "PCI429_3Interrupt");
    // register event handle within device via DeviceIoControl

    while (true)
    {
        DWORD waitRes = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
        ResetEvent(hEvent);

        // get output channel index which has generated an interrupt
        size_t channelIndex = ...;

        // private implementation holds pointers to output channels
        pImpl_->GetChannelOut(channelIndex)->InvokeInterrupCallback();
    }
}
```

---

But another device does not implement interrupts, so I have to "busy-wait" (sleep for the calculated expected time, then loop sleeping for small periods of time to adjust possible inaccuracies).

An object that implements interface `IArinc429ChannelOutput`:

- implements method `SingleOutput`, that initiates asynchronous output;
- implements method `WaitOutputFinished`, that waits until channel is running, then modifies its state to `stopped`;
- holds a thread that runs `WaitOutputFinished`;

```
void ArincECE206_1ChannelOutput::WaitOutputFinished(size_t words)
{
    // calculate expected period of time to sleep, using amount of words to transfer and channel output speed
    std::chrono::microseconds timeToSleep = ...;

    // 99% is enough
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeToSleep);

    // if channel is still running, wait for 1 more word.
    timeToSleep = Arinc429Values::TimeToTransfer(
            refImpl_.outputFreqs[ChannelIndex()],
            1);

    while(IsRunning())
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeToSleep);
        ++additionalWords;
    }

    mode_ = Arinc429OutMode::stopped;

    if (callbackOnFinishedOutput_)
        callbackOnFinishedOutput_();
}
```

Here is part of an API for output channel

```
struct ARINC429_API IArinc429ChannelOutput
{
    // 0 based index
    virtual size_t ChannelIndex() const = 0;
    virtual Arinc429OutMode OutputMode() const = 0;
    virtual Arinc429Freq Frequency() const = 0;
    virtual size_t BufferSize() const = 0;

    virtual void SetFinishOutputCallback(std::function<void()>&& fCallBack) = 0;

    // elements exceeding BufferSize are ignored
    // TODO: return future?
    virtual bool SingleOutput(array_view<const uint32_t> wordArray) = 0;

    virtual void StopOutput() = 0;

    virtual ~IArinc429ChannelOutput() = default;
};
```

Given the asynchronous nature of output, I think it would be convenient to return `std::future` from `SingleOutput`. And I see no problem in doing so for the second type of an Arinc429 device, since separate channel objects own their own separate waiting threads.

I chose to add a callback on finished output from the beginning since interrupts are implemented for the first device. Also callbacks are convenient to emit Qt signals from.

But `std::future` is more handy for synchronization and can be used to wait for an output to finish. Though it is also manageable using callbacks and condition variables, I do not find that approach rather convenient.

**What option to choose?**

**a. Define routine that registers and uses callbacks.**

**b. Define `std::future` as a return type for `SingleOutput`.**

**c. Define both. Is this reasonable or even possible? It implies calling `std::promise<R>::set_value` and than calling.**

---

Another question is about implementation.

I don't see a clear and simple way to implement returning `std::future` in case of a device that implements interrupts, since there is a common interrupt event and capturing thread for all the channels.

**How to provide futures for multiple output channel objects which all reside in different threads? See `ArincPCI429_3::CaptureInterrupt()`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked this question before I got familiar with [ASIO](https://think-async.com/Asio/) and [Executors](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/executors). They provide a [Universal Asynchronous Model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3747.pdf) API. That is, a template function can be **both** synchronous and asynchronous depending on a completion token.

Basically, a function would look like

```
template <typename CompletionT>
auto do_stuff(CompletionT &&token);
```

Depending on the type of a token, there result can be returned via a simple callback:
`do_stuff([](bool res){ return res;});`

If an synchronous behavior is needed, a special tag can be passed instead:

```
auto boolFuture = do_stuff(use_future);
bool res = boolFuture.get();
```